# Typescript: Array is empty after calling and passing it to function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, loops, recursion

Hi I am building function to recursively "denest" a object of following interface:

```
export interface IUnit {
 code: string
 artifacts: IArtifact[]
 units: IUnit[]
}
```

The idea is that I have a separate array that I returns with every immersion and after each return the returned array is "pushed" to local array and so on...

the function is as following:

```
  const denestList = async (incomingUnit: IUnit): Promise<{ allUnits: IUnit[], allArtifacts: IArtifact[] }> => {
    var units = [incomingUnit];
    var artifacts = [...incomingUnit.artifacts];

    //Array is full
    console.log(unit.units)

    //Array is empty
    console.log(unit.units.length)
    console.log([...unit.units])
    console.log(Array.from(unit.units)?.length)

    for (unit of incomingUnit.units) {
        console.log(unit.code)
        //Recursion happens here.
        var result = await denestList(unit)

        units.push(...result.allUnits)
        artifacts.push(...result.allArtifacts)
    }

    return { allUnits: units, allArtifacts: artifacts }
}
```

The problem is that `for (unit of incomingUnit.units)` never happens. When I log `unit.units` it shows array full of `IArtifact[]`, but when I run `console.log(unit.units.length)` it return `0`.

Here is how to "denestList" function is called:

```
useEffect(() => {
    asyncStart(unit)
}, []);


const asyncStart = async (mainUnit: IUnit) => {
    var result = await denestList(mainUnit);

    setAllUnits(result.allUnits)
    setAllArtifacts(result.allArtifacts)
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you make sure `mainUnit` has been properly loaded/resolved in case that data is generated by an async function?

Comment: I think so.  I can easily do  `console.log(mainUnit.units.length)`  and It returns correct number. Its just not empty. I tried to make copy, out of  `mainUnit` and pass it instead, but when I try logging it in `denestList` it is still empty.

Comment: in order to answer this, we should first know how you gain `mainUnit`. Could you reproduce your issue if you hard-code some examplary object with some data as `mainUnit`?